# How to implement the new firebase SMS multi-factor authentication in a Flutter Web App?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter-web

I would like to implement the new [feature](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases#auth-identity-platform) in my Flutter web app, but I am not sure how.

Is there maybe a way to make it work with flutterfire? https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/phone#web-signinwithphonenumber

Thanks